# How to make the application FireandForget?

Tags: .net-4.0, fire-and-forget

Below is the code I have used to develop Http Module in .Net 4.0. But when program runs I find it waiting for few seconds for the application to run. But I want it to be FireAndForget()[shouls not wait for the result]. How can I make it FireAndForget?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SourceIPModuleNet4
{
    public class HttpModule4 : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication app)
        {
            app.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(OnBegin, OnEnd);
        }

        private IAsyncResult OnBegin(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(extraData);
            DoAsyncWork(HttpContext.Current).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                }
                if (cb != null) cb(tcs.Task);
            });
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        private void OnEnd(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

        }

        private async Task DoAsyncWork(HttpContext ctx)
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            Thread.Sleep(10000) // in milliseconds
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://foo.com");

            // use result


        }

    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET 4.0 does not support `async` and `await`; the code will compile but not run correctly. Did you mean ASP.NET 4.5?

Comment: Hi stephen. I meant .Net 4.0. This application I have already built in 4.5 wanted the same app in 4.0. Yes, asyn and awit are not supported in 4.0, but have installed nuget packages for these. How can I use fire and forget for this? Is the app working asynchronosuly? How to check? Thanks

Comment: The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package does *not* work correctly on ASP.NET 4 projects, and there is no way to make it work. Sorry, `async` is not supported on ASP.NET 4.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. What is the alternative for this application? any suggestions?

Comment: A proper architecture would be a reliable queue (Azure queue / MSMQ) that sends the work to an independent process (Azure webjob / Win32 service).